# Change Unicode to UTF-8 | PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, unicode, utf-8

When I use `Write-Host` in my PowerShell script, the output looks like this: ????? ?????.

This happens because I'm entering strings in Arabic with `Write-Host`, and it seems that PowerShell doesn't support Arabic...

How do I print text using `Write-Host`, but in unicode `UTF-8` (which supports Arabic).

Example: `Write-Host "مرحباً بالعالم"`
The output in this case will be: ????? ?????

Any solutions?

Comment: `Write-Host` certainly supports unicode, what file encoding does your script itself have?

Comment: I'm supposing this happens on Windows Powershell not Core, right?

Comment: It works fine in the ise.  The console just can't display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fixed

You need to set a font that supports those characters. Like [Cascadia Code PL](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code#font-variants)

Note: The non-PL version didn't work, so get the PL one.

You might have to set the console encoding as well. Unless you really need a different encoding, default to `utf8` is a good idea.

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

[image]

### Before

[image]

I didn't actually need `wt` here, I'd suggest it. **windowsterminal** is a modern term, which is now an `inbox` app. Meaning it's default on windows going forward.

[image]

There's `utf8` that doesn't work on the term, that `wt` supports (both using the `cascadia code pl` font